# YII2 validation check unique between two fields without using active record

Tags: validation, yii2

I am using two fields "old_password" and "new_password". I want the error message if value in both fields are same. 
I am not using Activerecords.
I tried in model :

```
['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'a2']
```

but above code will work only for active record.
How can i get error message without using active record ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [compare](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#compare) validator instead of unique.

```
['new_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'old_password', 'operator' => '!='],
```

Because unique validator validates that the attribute value is unique across the table

Comment: I tried same
['new_password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'old_password', 'message' => 'New password cannot be same as old password.', 'on'=>'resetpassword']
 But it did not show me any error message when i enter same value in both field "new_password" and "old_password"

Comment: updated the answer. add `operator` parameter with value of `!=`

Answer (score 0):

If your model extend yii\base\Model, activeRecerd are not necessary  and you can use the rules function

```
public function rules()
{
    return [ 
      ['a1', 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => 'a2'],
    ];

}
```

for assign your validation rules

and in your controller you can perform validation invoking $model->validation

```
$model = new \app\models\YourForm();
```

like suggested [in Yii2 guide  for validating input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)

> ```
> // populate model attributes with user inputs
> $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());
> // which is equivalent to the following:
> // $model->attributes = \Yii::$app->request->post('ContactForm');
>
> if ($model->validate()) {
>     // all inputs are valid
>  } else {
>    // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
>   $errors = $model->errors;
> }
> ```

Comment: My model extends : 
class User extends Model implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
I tried the solution and got the following error  : <pre>PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Call to undefined method projectname\models\User::find()&#039; 

in /home/admin/php/www/projectname/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/UniqueValidator.php:100

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleFatalError()
#1 {main}</pre>

Comment: Show the the code (controller and class) related to the generated error .. because for User is necessary follow the identity Interface