# Yii2: customize error message when integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following code:

```
try {
    if ($model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $model->addError(null, $e->getMessage());
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

But when I do an insert into the database with duplicate keys, the error shown is not very friendly.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1-17' for key 'PRIMARY' The SQL being executed was: INSERT_QUERY

How do I customize the message when the error is due to duplicate keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would ideally validate the model before attempting to run a insert statement
have a look at the [unique validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique).

add a rule like this one to your model

```
// a1 and a2 need to be unique together, and they both will receive error message
[['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2'], 'message' => 'custom message'],
```

calling `model->save()` should just return false, adding the appropriate error message and will not throw any exception

---

edit:
what i'm trying to say in the comments, is that it's generally not a great idea to do things like this:

```
try {
    if ($model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $model->addError(null, $e->getMessage());
    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

this should just become

```
if ($model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
```

if any exception does occur, a real user under `prod` environment will just see a generic status 500 message. this is why we validate beforehand, to prevent exceptions not to sweep them under the rug.

doing this `$model->addError(null, $e->getMessage());` is particularly problematic as you risk exposing sensitive data to real world users which is a big security concern.

Comment: i would add that `Integrity constraint violation`s can happen in other cases as well (mostly invalid insert/update/delete of foreign key fields) . this example just prevents one scenario (duplicate pk). the correct approach would be to identify where these happen, and to prevent your application from attempting to run them via validation rules and error messages that are meaningful to the user, rather than customizing the exception message

Comment: Could you please explain your comment? You can edit your answer :) Thank you!

Comment: @Giest i'm trying to say that your focus should be on preventing [constraint violations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/ndb-error-codes-constraint-violation.html) by using stricter validation rules. I hope the edited answer helps you. cheers

Answer (score 2):

This approach did not work for me:

```
[['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2'], 'message' => 'custom message'],
```

I tried this one base on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794192/yii2-validation-check-unique-between-two-fields-without-using-active-record) and it worked:

```
['a1', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'a2', 'operator' => '!=', 'message' => 'your error message...'],
```

EDIT:

But if I am understanding your question correctly, this is not what you want. You want to catch the error caused because of inserting two equal primary keys in the same table? Why don´t you use an Auto incremental primary key?

Anyway you may use something like this:

```
[['id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => YourModel::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id' => 'YourModelId']],
```

Comment: quote from the answer you linked: `Because unique validator validates that the attribute value is unique across the table` also the linked question and OP's problem are different things entirely

Comment: Yes, I am not sure if I am understanding his problem correctly, that is why I edited my answer but I am not sure yet. I hope I am not confusing more than I am helping..

Comment: Yes, my table has two primary keys. I do not want to use auto increment since I do not want there to be more than one set of keys. I just want a message to replace the error "SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate ..."